# dlopen resolving of lazy symbols

Tags: c++, c, macos, dlopen, dyld

I wanted to write tool that mimic dlopen functionality by allocating executable area using `mmap` to store my dynamic library executable code.

Then, it has to locate symbols addresses by looking up at the symbols table. 
It seems to be working just fine, as I only have to find the API symbols addresses (offset for start address of allocated library + offset of symbols inside that library).. The indirect calls to other function within the library are correct since the opcode call uses relative address.

However, some special symbols are defined under section `__la_symbol_ptr` in `__DATA` segment which has both read and write permissions. 
it looks like dlopen should place the implementation upon runtime (see the empty stub below taken from hopper reverser tool).

I'd like to know what is the motivation to load this symbol upon runtime. and from where does the linker take the implementation, and who's in change to place the implementation, dlopen or dyld (code inside my executable) ?

```
    ; Section __la_symbol_ptr
    ; Range: [0x1010; 0x1018[ (8 bytes)
    ; File offset : [4112; 4120[ (8 bytes)
    ; Flags: 0x7
    ;   S_LAZY_SYMBOL_POINTERS

                 _printf_ptr:
0000000000001010         dq         _printf                                     ; DATA XREF=imp___stubs__printf
0000000000001018         db  0x00 ; '.'
0000000000001019         db  0x00 ; '.'
000000000000101a         db  0x00 ; '.'
000000000000101b         db  0x00 ; '.'
000000000000101c         db  0x00 ; '.'
000000000000101d         db  0x00 ; '.'
000000000000101e         db  0x00 ; '.'
000000000000101f         db  0x00 ; '.'
0000000000001020         db  0x00 ; '.'
...
..
.
```

Comment: So is the question about C or C++? They aren't the same language.

Comment: @tambre, my experiment was actually in C, but I also seek to understand the C++ case.